# RegEnumValueA returns 87 ("Invalid Parameter")

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am currently implementing functions and classes from Borland C++ Builder 5 in Visual Studio 2022. One of the classes is used to handle Windows registry IO, and one of its methods is supposed to return a list of values which the current key contains.

I am using Windows' `RegEnumValueA` function which, after passing correct arguments, always returns 87 – which stands for "Invalid Parameter".

The method looks as follows:

```
void __fastcall TRegistry::GetValueNames(TStrings* Strings)
{
    HKEY hKey                                     = m_CurrentKey;
    DWORD dwIndex                                 = 0;
    CHAR cValueName[TREG_MAX_VALUES_BUF_SIZE]     = {};
    LPSTR lpValueName                             = cValueName;
    DWORD dwValueBufSize                          = TREG_MAX_VALUES_BUF_SIZE;
    LPDWORD lpcchValueName                        = &dwValueBufSize;
    LPDWORD lpType                                = NULL;
    BYTE cData[TREG_MAX_VALUES_BUF_SIZE]          = {};
    LPBYTE lpData                                 = cData;
    LPDWORD lpcbData                              = NULL;

    long res = RegEnumValueA(hKey, dwIndex, lpValueName, lpcchValueName, NULL, lpType, lpData, lpcbData);
    while (res != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw(Exception(AnsiString(res)));
        }
        else
        {
            ++dwIndex;
            res = RegEnumValueA(hKey, dwIndex, lpValueName, lpcchValueName, NULL, lpType, lpData, lpcbData);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all the parameters are set correctly. My suspicion is that the `NULL` passed after `lpcchValueName` is causing this problem, since I've seen some people having the same issue after looking it up. Unfortunately, these were problems from years ago and were related to system-specific issues on e.g. Windows NT. The call to this method looks as follows:

```
int main()
{
    TRegistry* treg = new TRegistry; // Create a TRegistry object
    if (treg->OpenKey(AnsiString("TRegistryTest"), false)) // Open the TRegistryTest key
    {
        if (treg->OpenKey(AnsiString("subkey1"), true)) // Open the subkey1 key
        {
            TStringList ts; 
            treg->GetValueNames(&ts); // Write the value names into a TStringList
        }
    }
    delete treg;
}
```

`TStringList` is essentially a container which stores `AnsiString` values, which in turn are basically glorified `std::string`s.
I expected the `RegEnumValueA` function to exit with code 0 as long as there are registry values left to read - in this case, there are 4 values in total in TRegistryTest/subkey1.

Changing `TREG_MAX_VALUES_BUF_SIZE` does not influence the result at all - it's currently set to a value of 200.

Comment: Your `lpcbData` (set to `NULL`) looks invalid to me. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluea) say *This parameter can be NULL only if lpData is NULL.*. Your `lpData` is not NULL.

Comment: ... and I think you also need to reset `dwValueBufSize` before each call, as that will have been modified by the previous call.

Comment: Setting `lpcbData` to `&dwValueBufSize` fixed it, thanks :) as per resetting `dwValueBufSize`, won't it reset itself through re-definition at the beginning of each call?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation as to why you need to reset the maximum size variables.

Comment: The size value will be reset on each call to `TRegistry::GetValueNames` but not before each call to `RegEnumValueA` in the `while` loop.

Comment: *"I am using Windows' `RegEnumValueA` function"* - Why? Why not call `RegEnumValueW` and *know* which character encoding the returned data uses? It strikes me as odd than anyone would choose an API that's harder to use, can fail for more reasons, and offers decreased overall performance, compared to the Unicode API.

Comment: Would you care to explain the difference between `RegEnumValueA` and `RegEnumValueW`? I'm pretty new to this whole registry input-output thing and I am encountering different problems regarding reading non-string values, also using `RegGetValueA` and not `RegGetValueW`.

Comment: Windows' internal character encoding is UTF-16LE. If you call the ANSI-version of any given API the system will `1` convert narrow character strings to UTF-16LE using the calling thread's current code page, `2` call the Unicode API (the one with a trailing `W`), `3` convert output strings from UTF-16LE to codepage encoding using the thread's current code page. The final step is particularly susceptible to information loss, since not all Unicode code points can be represented in any given code page. You can cut out all those failure modes simply by calling the Unicode-version directly.

Comment: The ANSI-versions were really only meant to more easily port Win9x code to run on Windows NT systems. Today there is no reason ever to avoid calling the Unicode-versions, especially when writing new code. See [Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api) for the full story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `lpcbData` parameter, which you have set to `NULL` is invalid. This should be the address of a `DWORD` that specifies the size (in bytes) of the buffer pointed to by the `lpData` parameter (i.e. the size of the `cData` array).

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluea):

> `[in, out, optional] lpcbData`
>
> A pointer to a variable that specifies the size of the buffer pointed
> to by the `lpData` parameter, in bytes. When the function returns, the
> variable receives the number of bytes stored in the buffer.
>
> This parameter can be `NULL` only if `lpData` is `NULL`.

Also, note that, on success, the values in the variables pointed to by that `lpcbData` argument and by `lpcchValueName` (i.e. `dwValueBufSize`) will be modified to contain the *actual sizes* of the data/value returned. So, you should reset those before each call. For `lpcchValueName`, you would use a line like `dwValueBufSize = TREG_MAX_VALUES_BUF_SIZE;`, with similar code for the `lpcbData` target, depending on what you call that variable. (And I'm not sure it's an especially good idea to use the *same* size variable for both, as your comment seems to suggest.)

Comment: In one of the recent "updates" of the MSDN, Microsoft decided that it were a good idea to strip information from the documentation. Previously, the MSDN would contain the full [SAL Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations). If you look up the function signature in *winreg.h* you'll find that there's a lot more information than the transliterated MSDN documentation kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at C++Builder 5's source code for its `TRegistry::GetValueNames()` method, you would see that there are two big differences between its approach versus your approach:

- BCB5 first calls `RegQueryInfoKeyA()` to retrieve the number of values in the key, and the length of the longest value name in the key.  It then allocates a buffer of that length, and then runs a `for` loop calling `RegEnumValueA()` to retrieve the name for each index. But it ignores the return value, which means it *could* fail if the Registry key is modified mid-loop.

  Whereas you are (rightly so) calling `RegEnumValueA()` in a `while` loop until it reaches the end of the list or fails. But, you are using a fixed-length buffer to receive the names. `200` *should* be OK in practice for most systems, but you *should* use a dynamically allocated buffer and pay attention to `RegEnumValueA()`'s return value so you can know when it tells you that it needs additional buffer space that you can then allocate.
- BCB5 sets the `lpType`, `lpData`, and `lpcbData` parameters of `RegEnumValueA()` to `NULL`, since it does not need those data.

  Whereas you are setting the `lpData` parameter to the address of a local buffer, which is wrong (as other comments/answers have already pointed out), and unnecessary anyway since all you really want is each value's name and not its content.